# How can I update the keras.json file on Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I need to make some amendments to the keras.json file for a sagemaker notebook instance but I am unsure where it is located. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker!

You can find keras.json file located in /home/ec2-user/.keras .

Thanks,
Neelam